# Integrating local annotation processor project into gradle build

Tags: java, gradle, netbeans, annotations, annotation-processing

I've been working on a java project using Netbeans and its default ant-based build integration. Due to the insufficiency of ant I am planning on switching to a gradle-based build.

The problem is that the project is separated into three different modules:

- Annotations-module (containing several annotation processors)
- Database-module
- UI-module

The UI-module and the database-module use the annotations processor from the annotations module. The UI-module depends on the database-module.

The build setup I tried looks like the following:

```
if (!hasProperty('mainClass')) {
    ext.mainClass = ''
}

apply plugin: "net.ltgt.apt"

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar'])

  apt files('processor/Annotations.jar')
  compileOnly files('processor/Annotations.jar')
}
```

I tried to integrate the module dynamically, but the gradle build process did not generate the classes which should be generated by the annotations processor. Furthermore, I've tried it with precompiled versions of the annotations-module but this didn't work either.

My questions:

- How do I integrate the annotations-module so that the gradle build works?
- How do I integrate the annotations-module dynamically into the build process?

Comment: Do your processors have service declarations for discovery by ServiceLoader? If not, you should add them.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you'd use a [project dependency](https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:project_jar_dependencies)

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar'])
    apt project(':annotations')
    compileOnly project(':annotations')
}
```

Comment: This solution works for dynamically integrating the annotations-module but the build won't create the annotated classes. Is there an option to specify the different processors which are implemented in the annotations-module so that the gradle build can recognize them.

Comment: Now that you know how to access the `annotations.jar` from another module, I guess you'll need to look at the [net.ltgt.apt plugin documentation](https://github.com/tbroyer/gradle-apt-plugin) to use it